# How to serve same endpoint via HTTP and Websocket in Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I have an endpoint I'd like to make available on both HTTP (for the API) and on the websocket.

For instance, adding a new message could be done via a Socket "send" event, that will be handled on the server to process the request (checks the rights, create the necessary elements, etc).

These same actions could be possible by doing a POST request to /api/messages/ and would behave the same.

Since it's the same purpose and result, is there an efficient way to make the two works the same using Flask and Flask-SocketIO?

Answer (score 1):

The Socket.IO events don't have a request and a response like the HTTP methods have, so the inputs and outputs are different, making it impossible to use the same function for both.

But you could abstract the actual logic of your actions into auxiliary functions that you call from your HTTP route and your Socket.IO event handlers, that actually makes perfect sense if you want to offer your API over HTTP and Socket.IO both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if what I did was the same as what you're trying to do but here's what I did (trying to mock a connection to Graphite) which you could modify for your case:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


# You probably need to define more functions here (for connect, disconnect, etc)
@socketio.on('my meaningful name', namespace='/endpoint')
def endpoint_socket():
    emit([1, 2, 3])


@app.route("/endpoint/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def endpoint_http():
    return jsonify([1, 2, 3])


socketio.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, debug=True)
```

Comment: The idea is how to avoid repeating the core code for the same function?

Comment: You can just define a third function and call it from both of them, no? The only difference in my case was using `emit` versus the typical flask return.

Comment: Yes, that would be the basic idea, but in this case, for every endpoint, I will have to create three functions (the core, the HTTP and the websocket). I was hoping there was a better way to do that, but maybe not ;)

Comment: I can't see how, but I haven't been using sockets for long. If you want something that's more reusable I would try creating a decorator around your "core" function that under the hood defines wraps it twice. That way you use the decorator and define your function only once. Want me to edit the answer (a bit later today) to show how?

Comment: That's exactly what I did ;)